# A strengthened version of Noether's normalisation lemma?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Noether's normalisation lemma says that if $R$ is an integral domain, finitely generated over a field $k$, with transcendence degree $n$ over $k$, then there exist elements $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots x_{n} \in R$, algebraically independent over $k$, such that $R$ is integally dependent on the subring $k[x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}]$ generated by the $x$'s.

I am interested in knowing if there is a strengthened version of this where in addition we can arrange for $R$ to be separable over $k[x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots x_{n}]$. Looking at the proof which appears in Mumford's "Introduction to Algebraic Geometry", it seems as though that proof can be modified to prove this stronger result. Is this something which has been noted in the literature before? A reference would be very helpful.

Comment: Clearly not if $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ is not separable over $k$. Otherwise, I think it's true. I suggest you have a look at Bourbaki.

Comment: My recollection is that there is even a way to do something like this in the complete local case (where $k$ is the residue field as well).  But I don't remember where I saw it.

Comment: @KarlSchwede You're remembering part of the Cohen Structure Theorems.  One of the theorems says that if $R$ is a complete Noetherian local equicharacteristic commutative ring, $x_1, \ldots, x_d$ is any system of parameters, and $K$ is a coefficient field, then $x_1, \ldots, x_d$ are analytically independent over $K$ and $R$ is module-finite over the (formal power series) subring $K[[x_1, \ldots, x_d]]$.  See the Theorem on p. 8 of Mel's notes: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/supStructure.pdf.  However, I'm not sure about the separability part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes [when, as noted by Laurent Moret-Bailly, $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ is separable over $k$]. See David Eisenbud 'Commutative Algebra With a View Toward Algebraic Geometry' Corollary 16.18 about this.

[Edit:] Here is the theorem: if $R$ is an integral domain, finitely generated over a field $k$, with transcendence degree $n$ over $k$, and assume that $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ is separable over $k$, then there exist elements $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n\in R$, algebraically independent over $k$, such that $R$ is integrally dependent on the subring $k[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$, and $R$ is separable over $k[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$.

Comment: Yes to what? Moret-Bailly's comment shows it can't be true in general.